# ComplexContourPlot isn't showing nothing except a blank pane

Tags: plotting, complex

I am trying to have a contour plot of the following function:

$f(z) = \dfrac{2^{-iz}\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{iz+b}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{iz-b+1}{2}\right)}, ~ z \in \mathbb{C} ~\text{with}~ \Re{(z)},\Im{(z)} \ge 0$

But it is not working!

```
zmax = 20;
init = 0.1I;
b = 5;
ComplexContourPlot[Sqrt[Pi]2^(-I z)/(Gamma[(I z+b)/2+1]Gamma[(I z-b+1)/2]),{z, 0+0I, zmax+I zmax}]
```

**Output:**

[image: blank pane]

Now how to resolve?

Comment: `b = 5;Sqrt[Pi] 2^(-I z)/(Gamma[(I z + b)/2 + 1] Gamma[(I z - b + 1)/2]) /. 
 z -> 15. + 15.*I` results in `-5.75345*10^27 - 5.13538*10^27 I`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that ComplexContourPlot takes real function for making the plot.
From documentation:

> Plot a contour map of a real function of a complex variable.
> Hence the white region. You can use something like:

```
Clear[b, z, zmax];
f[z_, b_] := (Sqrt[Pi]*2^(-z*I))/(Gamma[1 + (b + z*I)/2]*
     Gamma[(1/2) + (-b + z*I)/2]);
zmax = 3;
init = 0.1*I;
ComplexPlot[f[z, 5], {z, init, zmax + zmax*I}]
```

which will give the output as,
[image]

or you can plot real and imaginary parts as contour lines:

```
ComplexContourPlot[ReIm[f[z, 5]], {z, init, zmax + zmax*I}]
```

[image]

you can also plot the absolute value like:

```
ComplexContourPlot[Abs[f[z, 5]], {z, init, zmax + zmax*I}]
```

Hope this answer your question.